# How to trigger dismiss of a popup window android

Tags: android

I have a popupwindow class, which is used to display a popupwindow by clicking a button on the MainActivity.

Now the popup window has basically a listview. THe onItemClick Handler is in the derived class of popupWindow.

My Question is how to trigger the dismiss of popupWIndow from onItemClickHandler of the derived class, so that the memory leak would not happen.

Comment: I thought of moving the OnItemClickHandler to MainActivty But that would not be clean.

Comment: can you list your current code (activity, listview and popupwindow )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used plain messages and  handleMessage and it worked